# Empty error log in CodenameOne build

Tags: codenameone

I just tried to build my application on the server, but it didn't work and generated an error.txt, though this file is empty?

Any idea why this is?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest sending a new build, there might have been a failure with the error report.

If this persists you should file an issue and also mention the platform you are building for since the backend logic for every platform is completely different.

Comment: Thanks, I can't try again yet but will do so tomorrow!